# Review Section is lately very slow

Tags: support, review, performance

I've notices in the last weeks that the StackOverflow [Review Section](https://stackoverflow.com/review) became very slow. It takes several seconds to load and from time to time it doesn't load at all.

Did you notice the same? I don't think it's a problem of my network, because the other site sections are running fine as before.

Comment: Just 5 mins ago it gave me a timeout error:
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/review)